# Which EF (code, model or database) is good for starting an application from scratch?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I am going to start an MVC 4.0 application based on Entity Framework, but I am inexperienced in EF so I'm looking for some real world advice. Which EF (code, model or database) is good for starting an application from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real-world applications usually use database first approach, because the software architect usually makes the database diagram first.

But if you're inexperienced with EF, I guess code-first would help you understand better what ORM-means and how it works.

This is a very good tutorial.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Personally, I started with database-first approach, generating the models automatically from EF. At first, I learned how to work with them, but I didn't really understood how they work. After a while, as the application was growing, I figured out what's really beneath EF.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Definitely i will go through with your link.